# Grep and counting matching lines

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a rather complicated grep and awk pattern that I use to get reports out of log files. I works great and I generate a nice light-HTML table that gets emailed to the people who need it.

I would like to add, for each section (each grep) a count of the elements in that section.

grep -c doesn't help because it *only* returns a count and I don't want to run the grep twice fore every log file for every section.

Everything runs inside a bash script, which also generates the HTML. I can number the rows using CSS, but getting the total count would be great.

The grep/awk is several lines long, and the end of it is the awk that generates the html:

```
 ...| awk '{print "<tr><td class=\"rightq\"> \
 <a href=\"mailto:admin@example.com?Subject=\ 
 "ENVIRON["DAY"]"%20"$1"&Body="ENVIRON["aBODY"]"\">" \
 $1"</a></td><td class=\"rightz\">"$2"</td><td>"$4"</td></tr>"}'
```

Comment: So, what are these "sections" you're talking about? What exactly do you want to count, and how do you want to show the results? Why do you use both `grep` and `awk` to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
... | awk '{ print "..." ; c++} 
  END { printf "<tr><th>%d lines</th>...</tr>",c}'
```

where

- `c` will count number of line (I assume that greping occur before the pipe)
- `END` is a special awk statement run .. ath the end.